# Apple Store product subscribe error with An unknown error occurred

Tags: codenameone

I add an SKU as an auto-renewable subscription on App Store Connect. I have codes below in the main class.

```
public static final String SKU_TW_1_YEAR="com.visionx.tw.subscribe.1year.2"; 


Purchas iap = Purchase.getInAppPurchase();
// Define a receipt loader
iap.setReceiptStore(createReceiptStore());
iap.subscribe(SKU_TW_1_YEAR);

@Override
public void itemPurchaseError(String sku, String errorMessage) {
    ToastBar.showErrorMessage("!subscribe_failure:"+errorMessage);
}
```

The callback procedure `itemPurchaseError` is called with an error message:

> An unknown error occurred

Are there any procedures I can follow to check the settings of App Store connect or debug for solving this problem?

I have a screenshot of the SKU setting on `App store connect` for checking.
[image]

I run my App on my iPhone 7 through Xcode for subscribing my pdoduct. The console on Xcode shows messages below.

`2022-07-17 13:33:41.976707+0800 VisionClass[8023:356071] Reachability Flag Status: -R t------ networkStatusForFlags 2022-07-17 13:34:55.142646+0800 VisionClass[8023:355757] SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing 2022-07-17 13:34:56.593077+0800 VisionClass[8023:356563] <SKPaymentQueue: 0x281cecd00>: Payment completed with error: Error Domain=ASDServerErrorDomain Code=3502 "This item is not available." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This item is not available.} 2022-07-17 13:34:56.597138+0800 VisionClass[8023:355757] Transaction error Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "An unknown error occurred" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, NSUnderlyingError=0x288dc2c10 {Error Domain=ASDServerErrorDomain Code=3502 "This item is not available." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This item is not available.}}}`

Comment: You missed a double quote in line 1. Obvious syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, copy mistake. I have the double quote in the code actually.

Comment: See the itunes connect testing section here: https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html#_itunes_connect_setup

Comment: I have already followed the procedures described in the section. Please help.

Comment: There isn't much I can do without more information. What's going on in the server side, does the process return a receipt there? Did you look into the native device console to see if there are additional details? Is this an error in the sandbox or production environments? Are you sure both are synced properly in regards to the product? Did you try this on a fresh device (switching between production/dev doesn't always work for devices).

Comment: It is not related to the server side. The process hasn't returned a receipt ( itempurchased is not called so as the submitReceipt). How do I look into the native device console? The simulator and google environment works well on both of client and modified server side except Apple app store connect.
I have modified the IAP demo server described in section 9 for google api upgrade from v2 to v3 and v2 is not supported by Google now. 
Is there any upgrade of Apple app store that codename1 payment library doesn't support?

Comment: The error is in the sandbox environment.

Comment: We're talking itunes right now, not Google. You can use the native logging cn1lib to have native logs sent to the same logger output file. Ideally if you have access to xcode you can look at the device console through there. Also try other devices, a lot of stuff doesn't work well in switching between environments in iOS. Just rebooting might not be enough in all cases.

Comment: Yes, the issue is in iTunes. Does codename1's payment library have logs sent to the output file on iPhone? How do I output the file from my iPhone 7 for you to check?
I have tried my app on iPhone 7 and iPad. Both of them have the same error message.

Comment: `if you have access to xcode you can look at the device console through there`
Do you mean sending iOS AppStore build with including source option. 
Run the source on xcode and check the console output. What is the device console?
Sorry, I have never used xcode before.

Comment: You can do that for sure. That's pretty easy relatively. You can also just launch xcode while the device is connected. E.g. this seems like a nice tutorial for that: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-collect-ios-console-logs-apple-configurator-2-or-xcode

Comment: I post the error messages on my question. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error messages on the console, I add the bank account and tax information. I can subscribe to my product now.
Thank you.